# Making Low Profile PCI Card

Tags: pci, low-profile

I have a PCI Card that can fit into a MicroATX case if the bracket was cut to a low profile size. Is there a way to cut the metal of the PCI card cleanly and will I have any issues such as grounding for doing this?

This is a picture of the card.

[image: ATi TV Wonder 650]

Comment: I have a Black Gold twin-tuner DVB-T TV card that looks very much like that one (except it has two tuners and is PCIe), and it came with both brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to unscrew the rings holding the bracket on the coaxial connectors.  It should just fall off after that.  You may also be able to buy a shorter bracket online.  Cutting the bracket I guess is an option but I would do it OFF the card to avoid vibration and static.

Comment: @user: If you can't get an exact-match short bracket, perhaps you can get a low-profile bracket with no holes and drill your own. I would think that would be easier and have better results than trying to cut down the existing one. You may even already have some of these solid brackets that came with your case.

Comment: Trouble with using blanking brackets is they don't have any tabs to screw the bracket to the board so you'd be relying on the mechanical strength of the screwed on connectors to do this - mind you, in this case they would probably do the job compared to, say, a standard RJ45 socket that has no mechanical connection to the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to do it, I'd take it off first, as Chris Nava says.

Although you could drill a hole (if needed) for the mounting screw (if present) and make a 90 degree bend in the top, the other way I have seen this done is to just cut the top across so that it is slightly higher than the top of the backplate gap in the case (or fits tight against a feature of the case (if possible)), fit the card and then run some hot melt glue along the inside edges of the bracket to secure it to the case and then put lines of hot melt glue along both edges of the board to lock the card into the PCI slot - the latter being more relevant for PCI-e cards that have smaller connectors and thus could come out easier if the outside sockets are pushed too hard. The advantage of hot melt is that it will not damage the connector plastics or PCB (no strong solvents) and can easily be removed with a blade if the card needs to come out.

Mind you, all this is irrelevant if a low-profile bracket can be purchased!

Comment: There is no low profile card option. This is an old but good card. I want to still use it. If you look there's a notch where I can cut for low profile.